# Calling fragment method throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I actually have two activities. The first is calling the other to get a result.

The startActivityForResult part is fine. Request code and Result code are ok.

But it throws *NullPointerException on Context.getResources()* and I can't understand why. I know what this exception means, but in this specific case, I don't understand.

Here is my source code :

Before onCreate (in class scope)

```
ComponentsFragment componentsFragment;
```

In onCreate

```
componentsFragment = new ComponentsFragment();
```

On button click event

```
Intent i = new Intent(ReportActivity.this, ManageComponentsActivity.class);
i.putExtra("action", PICK_COMPONENT_REQUEST);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_COMPONENT_REQUEST);
```

In the second activity

```
Toast.makeText(c, "*****activity started for result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Component component = (Component) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Toast.makeText(c, "****component : " + component.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("component_name", component.getName());
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

finish();
```

In the first activity - onActivityResult

```
if (requestCode == PICK_COMPONENT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "*****on activity result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "*****component_name : " + data.getStringExtra("component_name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "*****report_id : " + report_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "*****category_id : " + category_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {

        if (componentsFragment == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "*****componentsFragment IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //componentsFragment.AddComponentItem(data.getStringExtra("component_name"), report_id, category_id);
        componentsFragment.AddComponentItem("Fenêtre", "1", "1");


        componentsFragment.RefreshList("1", "1");

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

For an example component of 'Kitchen', the actual output is :

---

*****activity started for result

*****component : Kitchen

*****on activity result

*****component_name : Kitchen

*****report_id : 1

*****category_id : 1

THROWS EXCEPTION

---

So componentsFragment is not null...

Sorry, I have some problem with my logcat so I actually work with Toasts :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the replace fragment transaction.

I did not use **componentsFragment** as describe above in this transaction, but a newly created one.

```
    ComponentsFragment fragment = new CommponentsFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null); // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
```

This line :

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```

Has to be replaced by :

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, componentsFragment);
```

And this one should be removed :

```
ComponentsFragment fragment = new CommponentsFragment();
```